# get VOIP Token on ios10

Tags: ios10, swift2

I can't have the voip token with this function

```
func registerVoipNotifications() {
    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]
}
```

and

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry,
                  didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials,
                                           forType type: String) {

    //print out the VoIP token. We will use this to test the nofications.
    let voipToken = credentials.token
    self.getSipSetting("\(voipToken)")

}
```

but i can't enter in 'didUpdatePushCredentials'.

With ios9, i don't have this problem.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

- Have you enabled the Push notifications in your project Capabilities?
- have you added the SSL certificates (Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificates) in your app id configuration?